# Type 13 mismatch error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm receiving a type 13 mismatch error with Excel VBA.  This script checks two columns and locks cells in a column once a change is made, or doesn't lock it if the user clicks the cell and clicks off without any changes.  Line 5 is apparently the culprit.  Any help is much appreciated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim A As Range
Set A = Union(Range("I:I"), Range("J:J"))
If Intersect(Target, A) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If Target.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="YourPassword"
Target.Locked = True
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="YourPassword"
End Sub
```

Comment: **Target** is the cell or **cells** that have been changed. If Target is more than a single cell (e.g. pasted block of values, etc) then Target does not have a `.Value`. Add `If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub` to the top of the code or loop through Target, examining each cell within Target for the .Value. Also, don't use the [ActiveSheet property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in a Worksheet_Change.

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thank you my friend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target is the cell or cells that have been changed. If Target is more than a single cell (e.g. pasted block of values, etc) then Target does not have a .Value. Add `If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub` to the top of the code or loop through Target, examining each cell within Target for the .Value.

Example of the latter,

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Union(Range("I:I"), Range("J:J"))) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="YourPassword"
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Dim ij As Range
        For Each ij In Intersect(Target, Union(Range("I:I"), Range("J:J")))
            If ij.Value <> "" Then
                ij.Locked = True
            End If
        Next ij
    End If
bm_Safe_Exit:
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="YourPassword"
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Additionally, it is not considered a 'best practise' to use the [ActiveSheet property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in a [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro.

Comment: This was just what I was looking for.  Thank you!